# Java Socketio Not Emitting

Tags: java, socket.io

I have the following java socketio code

```
package me.summit.socketchatmc;

import java.net.URI;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import static io.socket.client.IO.socket;

public class socketclient {
    Socket sock;
    private String uri="http://localhost";

    public void start(){

        sock = IO.socket(URI.create(uri));
        sock.connect();

        System.out.println("Socket connected");

        sock.emit("message", "Hi from Java Plugin!");
        System.out.println("Emitted message");

    }

    public void disconnect(){
        sock.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Socket disconnected");
    }

}
```

(It's in a spigot plugin)
I call it in the Main.Java function like this

```
    socketclient sock = new socketclient();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        //getLogger().info("onEnable is called!");

        sock.start();

        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this,this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        //getLogger().info("onDisable is called!");
        sock.disconnect();
    }
```

However, when I run the java plugin, it says that it emits the message
[picture of java plugin running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvGOP.png)

but when I check the socketio part, nothing is connected or emitted [picture of socketio server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlcia.png)

For reference, here is my socketio server code

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const options = {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  } 
};
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, options);
const cors = require('cors')


app.use(cors());
app.use(
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.ip+": "+req.path);
    next();
    }
);


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('hi');
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("join", socket.id);
    console.log(socket.id+" has joined");
  
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit("leave", socket.id);
        console.log(socket.id+' disconnected');
    });
    
    socket.on('message', (elem1) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("message", elem1, socket.id);
        console.log(socket.id+' said '+elem1);
    });
  
});

httpServer.listen(80);
console.log("Listening on *:80");
```